# Trigonometry Issue causing distortion when drawing floor textures in raycaster

Tags: javascript, trigonometry, texture-mapping, raycasting

I'm creating a game with raycasted 3D graphics like Wolfenstein 3D but using line segments instead of a grid of blocks for walls. Everything is fine when drawing the floors until rotating the player view.
[the floor should be aligned against the walls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3YPg.png)
Here is the view in 2D, with each pixel on the floor on the screen rendered as a blue point:
[In the top image is when the player's rotation is Math.PI. In the bottom image it is rotated slightly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn2Wc.png)
A significant feature of this is the beginning of the cone of points is aligned along the y axis. It should look like a frustrum.

Here is the code I am using to find the x and y coordinates of each point where a texture is drawn on the floor. This code is run for each x value on the screen.

The variable "projPlane" is the projection plane, which is the size of the screen.
projDistance is the distance from the player to the projection plane so that it fits within the field of view, or `(projPlane.width/2)/Math.tan(VectorMath.toRadians(fov/2))`
pHeight is the players height.
The variable "x" is the x value of the row being rendered on the screen.

```
    //FLOOR TEXTURE
    var floorSize = Math.floor((projPlane.height-wallSize)/2); //draw the floor from under the wall
    var floorTextureIndex = 1;
    //for texture y
    if(floorSize > 0){ // values need to be positive
        //find the point on the floor

        var textureWidth = textures[floorTextureIndex].textureImage.width;
        var textureHeight = textures[floorTextureIndex].textureImage.height;
        //console.log(coordX);
        for (var ty = 0; ty < floorSize; ty++){
            //angle is tan
            var yAngle = projPlane.distance / (ty + wallSize/2); //ty + wallSize/2 is the point on the projection plane
            var yDistance = yAngle * pHeight; //pHeight is player height
            var worldY = player.y + Math.sin(player.vector)*yDistance;
            var coordY = Math.floor(worldY % (textureHeight));

            var xAngle = Math.atan((projPlane.width/2 - x)/projPlane.distance);
            /*if(x < projPlane.width/2){//tangent of the angle in the projectionPlane
                xAngle = (x) / projPlane.distance;
            }
            else{
                xAngle = (x-projPlane.width) / projPlane.distance;
            }*/
            var xDistance = yDistance/Math.cos(xAngle);
            var worldX = player.x + Math.cos(player.vector - xAngle)*xDistance;
            //console.log(xDistance);
            var coordX = Math.floor(worldX % (textureWidth));//disable until I can get y
            floorPoints.push(new Point(worldX,worldY));

            var tempTexture = textures[floorTextureIndex];
            if(tempTexture.textureData[coordX] != undefined){
                // a different function drawns these to the screen in descending order
                floorTextureColors.push(tempTexture.textureData[coordX][coordY]);
            }
        };
    }
```

It doesn't seem to be an issue with the y value since the y coordinates of the floor texture seem to appear where they should.(EDIT: it actually was to do with the y value. Adding the xAngle to the player.vector when finding the y position returns a correct y position but there is still a "curved" distortion. I hope one of you can propose a more concrete solution.)

What I do to find the X coordinate is form a triangle with the distance from the player to the floor point as the opposite side the angle that the point makes with the player. The hypotenuse should be the magnitude of the distance to the point's x coordinate.

Then I multiply the cosine of the angle by the magnitude to get the x value.
It works whenever the character isn't pointing west and east. What is causing all the first points to have the same y value? I think that's the biggest clue on the distortion occurring here.

Comment: if you break your code down into concise chunks (i.e. a bunch of semantically named functions) then you can test each part of your code separately to find the problem.

Comment: I tried that, looked at what I had and came actually up with a partial solution. Still very distorted, but it works more!